# How to access the current CategoryData in a category page?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to create a Category Page specific CMS component.

Is there a currentCategoryService that is similar to the [CurrentProductService](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/injectables/CurrentProductService.html) in Spartacus injectables?

If not, what is the correct way to get the current category data (or at least the category code) in my new component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, currently we do not have anything similar to `CurrentProductService` for current category. Looking at the implementation of `CurrentProductService` you can see that it is using `RoutingService` and it's `getRouterState()` method (picture 1). You can create something similar for current category, because the router state consists of category informations (as seen below on picture 2).

**Picture 1:** `CurrentProductService`:

[image]

**Picture 2:** Router state contents:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, I will create the CurrentCategoryService based on that information